# long press gesture issue

Tags: iphone, ios4, uigesturerecognizer

I have long press gesture in my app and it works good in ios 5.0 but in ios 4.3 i have exception. Here what i see in debug

```
[UILongPressGestureRecognizer initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5863360
2012-03-23 23:39:30.384 Woods2[289:ef03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILongPressGestureRecognizer initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5863360'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x013415a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01ce6313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x013430bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x012b2966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x012b2522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x005bb9fd UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592
    6   UIKit                               0x005bb2f5 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 792
    7   UIKit                               0x005bc6ac -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398
    8   UIKit                               0x004d0c54 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 834
    9   UIKit                               0x004d2ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    10  UIKit                               0x00388628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    11  UIKit                               0x00386134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    12  UIKit                               0x0038600e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    13  Woods2                              0x00004f37 -[FirstViewController viewDidLoad] + 1671
    14  UIKit                               0x00386089 -[UIViewController view] + 179
    15  UIKit                               0x00398f54 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 120
    16  UIKit                               0x00397aaa -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
    17  UIKit                               0x003998a2 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 263
    18  UIKit                               0x00399d5e -[UITabBarController viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 170
    19  UIKit                               0x004aa2e9 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 226
    20  QuartzCore                          0x019faa5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    21  QuartzCore                          0x019fcddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    22  QuartzCore                          0x019a20b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    23  QuartzCore                          0x019a3294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    24  UIKit                               0x002d89c9 -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 39
    25  UIKit                               0x002d8e83 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 690
    26  UIKit                               0x002e3617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    27  UIKit                               0x002dbabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    28  UIKit                               0x002e0f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x015eb992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x01322944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x01282cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0127ff83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0127f840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0127f761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    35  UIKit                               0x002d87d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    36  UIKit                               0x002e4c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    37  Woods2                              0x00001c2a main + 170
    38  Woods2                              0x00001b75 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionkill
```

Thank you very much for help

Here is the some code in viewdidload

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.2; //user needs to press for 2 seconds
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
[lpgr release];
```

Comment: Can you confirm that handleLongPress: is implemented on the view controller that creates it.  (The same class that initWithTarget:self refers to)?

Comment: yes it is. I have mapView and this mapView has this code in viewdidload. SO what i have to do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That trace data is much better formatted now.  Now I see it's happening on the loadFromNib, not even when the user performs a long press.  And it makes sense especially if the nib was copied in from another project.

Please see if you can find a gesture recognizer in your nib.  If it's there, check the connections inspector.  It might have some invalid references, possibly to symbols in another project.  (You'll probably see a little "!" near one or more of the connections).

If you find that, then problem solved.  Delete it, and use the GR you've set up in code.  (or re-configure the pointers in the nib and comment out the code in viewDidLoad:).

Comment: i have sigabrt right now here MapViewCntroller *map = [[MapViewCntroller alloc] init];
        self.mapController = map;
        [self.view addSubview:self.mapController.view]; <----HERE IS ERROR
        [map release];